# Calling a Javascript onchange function which is present in Ajax response text after pasting the responseText

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a condition where in i have to call a javascript function onchange of a drop down which is actually present inside AJAX responseText. 
I am able to paste the response text from AJAX in to the parent html. But after that the javascript call is not happening.

Thanks in advance

This is the callback function to retrieve the ajax request:

```
function alertContentsInit(http_request, tag_target) { 
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) { 
        if (http_request.status == 200) { 
            // with this I get all the response that a PHP page build
            result = http_request.responseText; 

            document.getElementById(tag_target).innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Could you post your html and javascript code, maybe in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: // this is the callback function to retrieve the ajax request

function alertContentsInit(http_request, tag_target) {
if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
if (http_request.status == 200) {
result = http_request.responseText;
// with this I get all the response that a PHP page build
document.getElementById(tag_target).innerHTML = result;

Comment: I have a drop down in the ajax responsetext which is calling a javascript method onchange of its value. But the parent page where in i am pasting my ajax response is not calling the javascript method

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the onchange event handler in the success block **after the ajax call has been made**.

```
if (http_request.status == 200) { 
    result = http_request.responseText; 

    document.getElementById(tag_target).innerHTML = result;

    // Set your dropdown onchange event handler here
```

Comment: thanks for the response..
but after i paste my ajax response into the parent html and if i view the sourse of the html it still shows the old values instead of the updated on.
How to make the parent page loaded with values including the ajax response